# Make a sub list of a list, which is in an object stored List

Tags: java, list, arraylist, sublist

So I have an object Called Event which has the variables.

```
private String id;
private int x;
private int y;
private int distance;
private ArrayList<Double> list;
```

The list variable holds a list of doubles which represent a list of ticket prices for each event.

I have already sorted the list from Lowest to Highest, so the lowest price is at the top of the list. What I want to do is create a sublist, of 1, which will be the lowest price for each event.

I currently have a list of Events, for which I was able to create a sublist of 5.

```
 List<Event>resList = new ArrayList<>(unique1.subList(unique1.size() - 5, unique1.size()));
```

When I try to create a sublist of the List of doubles it will not do it. It gives me no errors but just wont create the list and returns the list unchanged.
This is what I tried.

```
public List<Event> finalTickets(List<Event> list){


        for(int i =0; i < list.size();i++){
            ArrayList<Double> onePrice = new ArrayList<Double>(list.get(i).getList().
                    subList(list.get(i).getList().size()-1, list.get(i).getList().size()));
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You are simply returning the list argument passed to the method, not the local onePrice sub-lists you create. The method subList will return a new List object and not modify the existing one. To be fair i have a hard time understanding what you're code is supposed to do. You create a couple of ArrayList<Double> and then do nothing with them.

Comment: What you are expecting here ? "What I want to do is create a sublist, of 1 which will be the lowest price for each event." ??

Comment: you want to return a sublist of 1 (does that mean one element in size?) in that case, why not return a Double?

why not put some time and effort in formulating the question, nobody can understand you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not changing the `Event` instances of the list you pass to the method, and the `ArrayList<Double>` instances you create inside the method are not referenced by any object.

In order to change the lists of these `Event`s you should modify the `Event` instances:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    ArrayList<Double> onePrice = new ArrayList<Double>(list.get(i).getList().
            subList(list.get(i).getList().size()-1, list.get(i).getList().size()));
    list.get(i).setList(onePrice);
}
```

Comment: That worked a treat thank you. I knew I was missing something small, I am unfamiliar with the setList() method.

Comment: @SeanMcGrath You're welcome! What do you mean by unfamiliar with the `setList` method? That's a method you should define in your own `Event` class.

Comment: Wow I feel embarrassed, I do have it. But for some reason I taught it was an inbuilt method of ArrayList. Anyways again thanks.